# Integrated raid exception detected. Volume (00: 009) is currently in state degraged

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012-r2, ibm-xseries

I have IBM x3200 M2 Server. Currently there are 2*500 GB hard drive installed in it. Raid 1 is configured in this server. I have hosted an windows application in this server.  Currently this server is alarming by glowing orange indicator.

So I restarted the server and it displays the following error.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoazR.jpg)

After this error windows stucked at starting windows and rebooted automatically after certain time. So I swapped the slot of hard drives and now windows has booted up.

I rebooted the server again and now it say's **Volume (00: 010) is currently in state degraged.**

Comparing the error messages I saw the number in volume is increased.

Does this error has anything to do with the hard drive ?

Any helps are welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how is this a Windows issue? The error you show is CLEARLY visible as a BIOS level error. The OS does not enter into this at all. It is not starting windows. It is stuck BEFORE even trying to boot from the disc.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this error has anything to do with the hard drive ?

Note that this is the ONLY question you ask, so I answer it.

OBVIOUSLY a Raid degraded error shown from the RAID BIOS (before even trying to load windows) indicates an issue with the hard discs, either now or at some point.

And as obvious this has NOTHING to do with Windows at all. The screenshot you provide shows a BIOS level error shown before trying to boot from the discs.

Time to start reading up on the documentation for the RAID controller you are using - something went very bad there. Fastest way to fix this obviously is to reinstall / apply the backups.